# Polynomial Time Traveling Salesman Using A Tree [Dynamic Programming]

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, traveling-salesman

If we have N cities, where each city is only a leaf of a binary tree is it possible to come up with a dynamic programming solution that is polynomial time? I'm trying to find the minimal distance between all the cities with the constraint of only being able to travel depth first. My approach is to start bottom up and calculate the optimum path to travel for each ancestor of the deepest internal nodes. So there will be 4 cities that are going to be evaluated during each of these operations by some distance function. Distance(x,y) = Distance (y,x). If there are 4 cities at each operation then we will have 8 possible solutions. All the other internal nodes will result in the summation of lower nodes. The root will basically be the summation of its children. Am I headed in the wrong direction here or what?

Comment: The traveling sales man problem is well known and is NP-Complete. Recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness

Comment: This is not really a travelling salesman problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to solve the TSP on a graph which happens to be a tree. The academic version of this problem seems to be to solve the TSP on graphs of "bounded treewidth" which is probably a good search term. http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~zdvir/apx11slides/erik-scribe.pdf contains a reference, "Frederic Dorn, Fedor V. Fomin, and Dimitrios M. Thilikos. Catalan structures and
dynamic programming in H-minor-free graphs. In SODA '08: Proceedings of the 19th
annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pages 631{640. SIAM, 2008.", to a paper which I suspect is of more interest to mathematicians than programmers.

Suppose you are given an optimal tour. Look at two children of an interior node and count the number of times this tour crosses the interior node. If it crosses it more than twice, you can shorten the tour by taking a short cut - break two of those crossings and turn them into links within each subtree instead of going from subtree to subtree. So in an optimal tour, at each interior node crossed, we have a path that visits all the cities in one subtree, a trip to the other subtree, a path that visits all the cities in that subtree, and then a trip back to connect up the tour.

An possibly inefficient but polynomial dynamic programming approach is therefore to compute, at each interior node, for each pair of cities within that interior node, the cost of the best trip from city A to city B, visiting all of the other cities beneath that node (or a marker that says "cities on same side - don't do this"). You can work this out for each interior node using the information computed from its children, and at the very top just consider all of the best paths on offer and the cost of the remaining link that makes a tour to work out the shortest tour.